# alternative to mouseover w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to change css of an element while a cursor either:

1. Hovers over, or
2. Drags another element over.

Both .hover() and .mouseover() seem to work fine on toll over, but neither one works for drag over. Is there anything else that would work?

Once the mouse moves away from the element it needs to go back to the previous state.

Thanks.

Comment: What don't you bind the event handler to both, the `mouseover` (or `mouseenter`) and `dragover` event? There is no event which covers both.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`dragover` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DragDrop/Drag_Operations).

Answer (score 2):

just bind both events to the same handler, like so:

```
var hoverHandler = function(e){
    /// do stuff
}
$('#myelement').mouseover(hoverHandler).bind('dragover', hoverHandler);
```

Comment: Like this?  var hoverHandler = function() {
     $(this).css("background-color","green");
  }, function() {
     $(this).css("background-color","red");
 }
 $("#myelement").hover(hoverHandler).dragover(hoverHandler);

Comment: Nope, try this: `var hoverHandler = function() {
 $(this).css("background-color","green");
}
$("#myelement").mouseover(hoverHandler).bind('dragover',hoverHandler).mouseout(function(){$(this).css("background-color","red");});`